# Czech and slovak babel breaks \tikz\graph

Tags: babel, tikz-graphs

If I use czech or slovak babel and try to compile examples from documentation, the results are very disappointing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\begin{document}
     \tikz \graph { a -> {b, c} -> d };
\end{document}
```

[image: fail]

However, if I ommit the `\usepackage[slovak]{babel}`, results are as expected. Can I somehow use both packeges at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You only need to add TikZ library `babel`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,
               border=3mm]{standalone}% solution work at any documentclass
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,babel} % <-- added library "babel"

\begin{document}
     \tikz \graph { a -> {b, c} -> d };
\end{document}
```